# CSS grid-column ignoring elements added automatically

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to format a `div` such that the first element spans the entire length of the grid, with all element thereafter below it. However, the number of total elements is variable.

Therefore, my approach was to set `grid-column: 1 / -1;`

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. It looks like the `-1` doesn't update when the grid's size is increased. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #gridify {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: 20px 20px;
                grid-auto-flow: column;
            }
            p {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #gridify > *:first-child {
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
                grid-column: 1 / -1;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            let curNum = 1;
            function addNum() {
                let p = document.createElement("p");
                p.innerText = curNum++;
                document.getElementById("gridify").appendChild(p);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gridify">
            <p>Numbers</p>
        </div>
        <button onclick="addNum()">Add a number</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gvzq2c6/2/)

Initially, the header's `grid-column` is `1 / 2`. However, when numbers are added, this doesn't increase to `1 / 3`, `1 / 4`, etc. Is it possible to fix this?

P.S. I would like to avoid adding extra containers to my html, as well as DOM/style manipulation in JS. A pure CSS solution would be ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately `1 / -1` is not currently possible with implicitly created grids. Are you open to altering your HTML?

Comment: Or you could do something with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/emycd1hx/

Comment: @sol Thanks! I wanted to keep my example simple so I only had one row (the numbers). In what I am using this for, I need multiple rows. I'm going to mess with flexbox a bit more, though, and I'll let you know if I come up with anything. And I would prefer to not alter the html, but if it is unavoidable, so be it.

Comment: For multiple rows, you could remove `flex-grow` and give the numbers a minimum width --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/c9et0owp/

Comment: @sol sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant something along the lines of this:https://jsfiddle.net/emycd1hx/3/ Note that this is just a hack and wouldn't actually work in my case. What I'm trying to go for is to have the first row to be text, and the second to be an input.

Comment: sorry you've lost me!

Comment: Haha, alright. Here's basically what I'm looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/0gvzq2c6/24/ (note the comment in the CSS and JS), and I don't necessarily know how many options there will be. Sure this works, but I don't like it, as I am a strong believer of isolating content, style, and functionality. Hope this clears everything up